# How to exit an event listener thread safely in X11

Tags: c, xlib

I am currently reading on Xlib library in C. I want to create thread that listens to right button presses on my mouse and then does some action. The correct method for that is I understand XNextEvent(). From the documentation, I see that this function blocks until an event is received.

What happens though when the program running this thread needs to exit while the XNextEvent() is still blocked. Can it cause problems to close the Display that the XNextEvent is handling before that?

If it does, what is the safe way around it? Can the main thread somehow send a "fake" event that tells the thread that listens to the events that it is time to close?

Comment: In any non-trivial OS, requesting process termination from any thread is fine.  The OS zaps all other threads in tbe process, no matter if they are ready, blocked or running on another core.  Try not to introduce unnecessary code to your app: I call it 'premature stoptimization':)

Comment: @MartinJames What about the opened display? If I terminate the process, while the display is still opened won't it lead to some leaked ressources? I want to make sure that the thread that is accessing the X server is safely terminated before I close the access to that server.

Comment: Why not try it and see?  You may need to explicitly destroy such visual components..or not.